# pyOpenGL failing to create a vertex buffer object

Tags: python, opengl, buffer

I'm just starting out with OpenGL and trying to create a basic "hello world"-type OpenGL app using Python 2.7, pygame and pyOpenGL to render some 2D shapes using the GPU. When trying to create a vertex buffer for the vertex data:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 59, in main
    vertexbuffer = vbo.VBO([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [2.2, 2.2], [2.7, 2.7], [2.2, 3.2], [1.7, 2.7]])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL/arrays/vbo.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.set_array( data, size )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL/arrays/vbo.py", line 204, in set_array
     self.size = ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount( self.data )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL/arrays/arraydatatype.py", line 176, in arrayByteCount
    return cls.getHandler(value).arrayByteCount( value )
AttributeError: 'ListHandler' object has no attribute 'arrayByteCount'
```

`vbo.VBO` is `OpenGL.arrays.vbo.VBO`.

Very confused by this. Searching for this error message yields absolutely nothing specific.

Any insights?

EDIT: I thought I'd include the code that is executed before this VBO call.

```
def init(screen_size):
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size, HWSURFACE | OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)

    glViewport(0, 0, screen_size[0], screen_size[1])

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST)

    viewport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1, 10.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
```

The `vbo.VBO(...)` line from the traceback is called immediately after this `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. `vbo.VBO` wants numpy-type arrays (`numpy.array`), not normal lists.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying this is not an answer? I'd say it is, and I'd know, because I'm answering my own question here. Are you saying it's unclear? In this case, I'll edit to clarify.